# Put answer as an optional argument for multiple choice

Tags: macros, exam, auto-multiple-choice

I am using the following code at the moment to make Multiple Choice Questions with the options as the 5 arguments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,answers,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx,caption,color,subcaption,amsmath,amssymb,lmodern,textcomp,gensymb,ifpdf,ifthen,xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\oneparchoices}{\penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax}{\hfill}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\oneparchoices}{\penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax}{\hfill}{}{}

\newcommand{\mcq}[5]{%
    \begin{oneparchoices}
        \choice #1
        \choice #2
        \choice #3
        \choice #4
        \choice #5
    \end{oneparchoices}
}
    \begin{document}
        \mcq{uihoo}{eifhw2u}{fiwuhr}{fjwhf}{fnweir}
    \end{document}
```

I want to make it such that the answer can also be given as an argument (the 6th argument) but I can only see a tedious way of doing it at the moment by making 5 different new commands, each with `\correctchoice` as that choice. Like I'd need the above code but with

1. `\correctchoice #1` when defining a command such as `\mcqa` with the
   same 5 argument where A is the right answer.
2. `\correctchoice #2` when defining a command such as `\mcqb` with the same 5 argument where B is the right answer....

Any way to do it more compactly? Tried all the packages on CTAN. None I found suited for this.

Comment: You might be able to abuse `xparse` for the job with an argspec like `msmsmsmsm`. A star before a choice will mark it 'correct'. Either that, or get some expl3 programming in (which will certainly be more straightforward to read) :)

Comment: And I *truly doubt* you tried *all* of the packages on CTAN :)

Comment: Oh ya sorry I meant, by "all", all the related packages like all packages under the exam category, including several MCQ stuff...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could prefix the correct answer by * and test for it, using `\CorrectChoice` for this case and `\choice` for the others; then you can use the standard `exam` features for hiding or showing the correct choice: removing the `answers` option will hide the correct answers.

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  addpoints,
  answers,
  12pt
]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx,caption,color,subcaption,
  amsmath,amssymb,lmodern,textcomp,gensymb,ifpdf,ifthen,xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\oneparchoices}{\penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax}{\hfill}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\oneparchoices}{\penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax}{\hfill}{}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mcq}[5]{%
  \begin{oneparchoices}
  \check@choice #1\@nil
  \check@choice #2\@nil
  \check@choice #3\@nil
  \check@choice #4\@nil
  \check@choice #5\@nil
  \end{oneparchoices}
}
\def\check@choice#1#2\@nil{%
  \ifx*#1%
    \CorrectChoice #2%
  \else
    \choice #1#2%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mcq{No}{*Yes}{No}{No}{No}

\mcq{*Lie}{Yes}{No}{No}{No}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although the alignment of the B seems off, I think it should look fine when I don't have them right below/above each other.

Comment: @FahimAbdullah That's because you're using `\hfill` between items, not fixed alignment points, so only the spaces between items are equal and different sizes of the items will make them not aligned with other lists of answers. I wouldn't care: as you said, you have to look at them only below the question and “global” alignment is unimportant.

Comment: Oooh, this is clever :)

Answer (score 1):

You could abuse `xparse` for this by assuming the first argument is correct and allowing a star `*` to indicate an other correct answer.  By checking against all the arguments, you can toggle which are correct.

Note that this solution is shaky: it will allow multiple correct answers in choices 2–5, but each of these will cause choice 1 to be incorrect.  For TeXnical reasons, no more choices may be added to the command.

This will work, but please do not do this to your document.  It's a very flawed way of thinking and will do you a disservice as you continue using LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,answers,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx,caption,color,subcaption,amsmath,amssymb,lmodern,textcomp,gensymb,ifpdf,ifthen,xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\oneparchoices}{\penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax}{\hfill}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\oneparchoices}{\penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax}{\hfill}{}{}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mcq}{msmsmsmsm}{%
  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{\choice}{%
      \IfBooleanTF{#4}{\choice}{%
        \IfBooleanTF{#6}{\choice}{%
          \IfBooleanTF{#8}{\choice}{\correctchoice}}}}
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{\correctchoice}{\choice} #3
    \IfBooleanTF{#4}{\correctchoice}{\choice} #5
    \IfBooleanTF{#6}{\correctchoice}{\choice} #7
    \IfBooleanTF{#8}{\correctchoice}{\choice} #9
  \end{oneparchoices}}
\begin{document}
\mcq{uihoo}{eifhw2u}*{fiwuhr}{fjwhf}{fnweir}
\end{document}
```